Имитирование клика мышки в свернутом окне C#
Всем здравствуйте , у меня возникла проблема при клике в свернутом окне , хочу что бы мой будущий кликер выполнял работу пока я смотрю тот же ютуб
почему то я спокойно получаю размеры окна , но клики не выполняются(
    private void startBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr windowHandle = FindWindow(null, "Debug");
        if (windowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error finding BS window.");
        }
        else
        {
            RECT rect;
            if (GetWindowRect(windowHandle, out rect))
            {
                bsWidth = rect.Right - rect.Left;
                bsHeight = rect.Bottom - rect.Top;

                MessageBox.Show($"{bsWidth}, {bsHeight}");
                int x = 733;
                int y = 276;

                IntPtr lParam = (IntPtr)((y << 16) | (x & 0xFFFF));

                SendMessage(windowHandle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, (IntPtr)MK_LBUTTON, lParam);
                SendMessage(windowHandle, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, lParam);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Не нашел бс");
            }
        }
    }

